# How do I get the Color value from an RGB node with Python?

Tags: python, scripting, node-editor

I'm a seasoned programmer, but fairly new to blender and 3D-modeling in general. So to get an understanding of different properties I want to write  python scripts to create multiple renderings with different settings of various values.

In the example below I have figured out how to change the Volume Absorption Density, ex:

```
bpy.data.materials['MyMaterial'].node_tree.nodes['Volume Absorption'].inputs['Density'].default_value = 100
```

But not the RGB-node. It seems I cant even get the current values out of it. Some things I have tried:

```
bpy.data.materials['MyMaterial'].node_tree.nodes['RGB'].color
bpy.data.materials['MyMaterial'].node_tree.nodes['RGB'].color.r
bpy.data.materials['MyMaterial'].node_tree.nodes['RGB'].color.outputs['Color']
```

How do I **get** and **set** output values of the RGB-node in py python-script?

[image]

Comment: just fyi here's a script showing how you can build your nodes directly from python: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/35436/5334 and here's another https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/34609/5334

Answer (score 15, accepted):

<sup>Welcome to Blender.SE, UlfR.</sup>

Finding out a property in Blender is relatively easy. Make sure, you have python tooltips enabled (in the user preferences).

Then hover your mouse cursor over the property (in this case the color). A tooltip containing the python command will appear.

[image: tooltip]

The property you seek seems to be `outputs[0].default_value`.

```
def_rgb = bpy.data.materials['MyMaterial'].node_tree.nodes['RGB'].outputs[0].default_value
```

It is a `bpy_prop_array` by default, so you may want to convert it to a list.

```
float_values = list(def_rgb)
```

Comment: Miceterminator beat me to it by 3 minutes. I will leave this answer up, as it mentions the python tooltip and his doesn't you could accept his answer as the correct one however.

Comment: my problem was that bpy.data.materials[1].node_tree.nodes['RGB'].outputs[0].default_value = (1.0,1.0,0.5,1.0) works but bpy.data.materials[1].node_tree.nodes['RGB'].outputs[0].default_value produces nothing in the Python console. Converting it to list then displayed the hidden values.

Comment: You can also access the individual values directly from the `bpy_prop_array` via their indices, such as `def_rgb[0]`.

Answer (score 9):

As you already found you way to the node tree, the "Copy data path" option is generally very helpful:

Right click on the field you want to access and use the "Copy data path" option.

bpy.data.materials['MyMaterial'].node_tree.nodes['RGB'].outputs[0].default_value

You can also look at the answers [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/131786/245) and [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/42330/245)

[image: How to get data access to the data path]